# check if powerpoint is already open in Java?

Tags: java, process, runtime, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to open Microsoft power-point from Java code but before that i want to check if it is already opened,if already open that show it otherwise open new.

till now I write this

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start powerpnt");
```

this command open new power-point windows every time but I want to show already opened one if it is present .

thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is the complete code to check the process is already open or not
function CheckApplicationIsOpen.isOpenApplication() is return the status 'open' or 'close' 
in main checking the powerpoint exe is start of not using task manager instance

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package checkapplicationisopen;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ANGEL
 */
public class CheckApplicationIsOpen {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


    /***
     * 
     * @param applicationName : whatever application you want to check if it is already open or not
     * @return the result status if it is open then 'open', otherwise 'close' 
     */
    public static String isOpenApplication(String applicationName)
    {
        String result="";
        try {
            String line;
            String pidInfo ="";

            Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");

            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                pidInfo+=line+"\n";
            }
            System.out.println("Data : "+pidInfo);
            input.close();

            if(pidInfo.contains(applicationName))
            {
               System.out.println(applicationName+"is open");
               result="open";
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("PowerPoint is Not Open");
                result="close";
                //

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CheckApplicationIsOpen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            if(!CheckApplicationIsOpen.isOpenApplication("POWERPNT.EXE").equals("open"))
            {
                Process p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start powerpnt");
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("Application is Open");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sandip.But I also want that if powerpoint is running then it should be visible on top.here in your code if powerpoint is open then nothing happens.I want that if powerpoint open than its visibility should be set to true.

Comment: PowerPoint only allows a single instance of itself, so you'll either get the currently open instance (if any) or start a new instance.  The only oddity to be aware of is that sometimes there will be an invisible instance of PowerPnt.EXE, either because that instance has crashed and not completely closed itself down OR the user has the Preview pane visible in Windows Explorer and there's a PPT open in the preview pane.